# iFrame don't work the event drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have the next iframe:

```
<iframe class="container" id="Visualizar"></iframe>
```

and I want he do it an animation when the event DragOver is active, the animation was already working with this div:

```
<div class="container" id="Visualizar"></div>
```

but when I made the change to iframe stopped working, I have already checked the code and I have tried to fixed.

The next code is of the JS that add the animation to the event:

Set up variable

```
var container;
var one;
var two;
var three;
var four;
var signal;
```

I create the function that start on load

```
window.onload=function(){
```

I get the element that have the class 'container'

```
container = document.querySelector('.container');
//var container = document.getElementById(Visualizar);
```

And I add the events to the element

```
container.addEventListener('dragover',sobre,false);
container.addEventListener('dragleave',fuera,false);
container.addEventListener('drop',soltar,false);

};
```

here I add and remove the class 'over' to make the animation on CSS

```
function sobre(e){

e.preventDefault();
this.classList.add('over');

}

function fuera(e){

e.preventDefault();
this.classList.remove('over');

}

function soltar(e){

e.preventDefault();
this.classList.remove('over');

}
```

And this is a CSS that make the effect:

```
.over{

box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
transform: scale(1.04);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm struggling with your English a bit. Do you have a nearby friend who can help clarify?